# large buffer when json to dataframe for large twitter data

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I have a typical problem of working with 2-3 GB json files containing twitter stream data. The over 100k tweets have to be filtered for few details, such as, "full_text", "created_at",  "user.location", "id".

The computer hangs for hours while sifting through these. I need to shorten the code and better use computer resources for this purpose.

I need help for optimising the code in order to stop computer from hanging for hours. My code runs on jupyter notebook as follows:

```
tweet_data = []

for f in filelist:
    tweets_file = open(f, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    for line in tweets_file:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            if isinstance(tweet, dict):
                tweet_data.append(tweet)
        except:
            continue
    print("Downloaded {0} tweets.".format(len(tweet_data)))
    print(f)
```

Once this iteration is over then I try to load the tweet_data into dataframe as follows:

```
tweets = pd.DataFrame()
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data, errors='ignore')[["full_text", "created_at",  "user.location", "id"]]
```

The computer hangs at the second set of code lines for hours. I wish if the above two set codes could be merged into single with minimum use of computer resources so that multiple 1-2 gb files totaling 3-4 gb data can be processed from a folder.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. "in lacs" will be very confusing for a lot of people.

Comment: good, now what about my Question @James-z